# Not able to find the CoreSimulator folder

Tags: core-data, xcode6

I'm going through some Core Data tutorials and I am trying to identify the location of my .sqlite file.

I've used `NSLog` to get the path and it's here (which is as expected).

```
/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E3C3C4D6-AA2E-4364-8799-5B1032BAB06D/data/Containers/Data/Application/36E4A5A6-A610-4D3A-8684-49DEF07B6623/Documents/Core_Data.sqlite
```

When I use the finder to navigate to the Developer folder, I don't see the CoreSimulator folder.

I only see Applications, Documentation, Extras and Platforms.

Is there something I need to change to see this folder?

Comment: In Finder, press Cmd-Shift-G and paste the path.

Comment: You need to look under the Users directory **/Users/YOUR_NAME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/** or just put a **~** in front of that path.